# Show that set $A$ is linearly dependent to work out $\operatorname{span}(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors

I want to find out the $\operatorname{span}(A)$, $A=(x^4+1, x^3-x^2-x, x^4+x-2, 1)$, by showing that $A$ is linearly dependent. To do this I basically tried to use Gaussian elimination to bring the matrix into the rref, as following:

$$A=(x^4+1, x^3-x^2-x, x^4+x-2, 1)$$
$$α_1(x^4+1)+α_2(x^3-x^2-x)+α_3(x^4+x-2)+α_4(x^2+1)=x^4(α_1+α_3)+x^3(α_2)+x^2(-α_2+α_4)+x(-α_2+α_3)+(-2α_3+α_1)$$

$P(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx^1+e$

$$a=α_1+α_3, b=α_2, c=-α_2+α_2, d=-α_2+α_3, e=-2α_3+α_1$$

Using this I built an augmented matrix which looks like:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & c \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & d \\
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & e
\end{array}\right]$$

From here I did made this matrix into a Rref matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a-b-d\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & d+b \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & b+c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e-a+3d+3b
\end{array}\right]$$

Therefore $α_1=a-b-d$, $α_2=b$, $α_3=b+b$, $α_4=b+c$, $α_5=e-a+3d+3b$ but I'm not sure how I can use this to show that $A$ is linearly dependent and then use that to find $\operatorname{span}(A).$

Comment: Is the third polynomial $x^4 + x - 2$ or $x^2 + x - 2$?  You wrote one in the first line and the other below it.

Comment: Also, I'm confused--in the title and first line, you say you want to prove $A$ is linearly dependent, but in the last line you say independent.

Comment: @RaviFernando Its $x^4+x-2$ and linearly dependent. I just fixed the mistakes.

Comment: The four polynomials you write down form a linearly *independent* set. Your calculation showed this by proving that the rank of the associated matrix is $4$. (Actually, you calculated the rank of the transpose of the associated matrix, which is equivalent; but really you should write the polynomials as row vectors to find the linear relations among them. You're solving a different problem, namely determining whether an arbitrary polynomial $P$ is in the span.